# Empty strings created by netCDF4.stringtochar()

Tags: python, numpy, netcdf

I am using the `netCDF4.stringtochar()` function before saving an N-D array of strings before exporting to a netCDF file; however, the function adds empty strings between each character.

Is this a bug in the function and/or am I missing a simple fix to this issue?

Here is an example:

```
import netCDF4
import numpy as np

data = np.array([['AAAA', 'BBBB', 'AAAB', 'BAAA'],['BABA', 'ABAB', 'AABB', 'BBAA']])

data_char = netCDF4.stringtochar(data,encoding='utf-8')
```

data_char returns:

> array([[['A', '', '', '', 'A', '', '', '', 'A', '', '', '', 'A', '', '',
> ''],
> ['B', '', '', '', 'B', '', '', '', 'B', '', '', '', 'B', '', '',
> ''],
> ['A', '', '', '', 'A', '', '', '', 'A', '', '', '', 'B', '', '',
> ''],
> ['B', '', '', '', 'A', '', '', '', 'A', '', '', '', 'A', '', '',
> '']],
> [['B', '', '', '', 'A', '', '', '', 'B', '', '', '', 'A', '', '',
> ''],
> ['A', '', '', '', 'B', '', '', '', 'A', '', '', '', 'B', '', '',
> ''],
> ['A', '', '', '', 'A', '', '', '', 'B', '', '', '', 'B', '', '',
> ''],
> ['B', '', '', '', 'B', '', '', '', 'A', '', '', '', 'A', '', '',
> '']]], dtype='<U1')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the [documentation](https://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/#stringtochar) says that a `u` or `s` datatype can be provided, the issue is fixed when manually setting the dtype to 's4'.